# how can I let other people download my app

Tags: python-3.x, windows

so I created a little calculator app and I wanna let my friends download it so they can use it, but how can they download it, how do I share it to other people

Comment: Put it on github, on your website, put it into S3, whatever you want and then share the link to the location.

Comment: [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/) could run it in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Note that in this answer I'm assuming that your calculator has no dependencies outside the Python standard library.]

For ms-windows there are basically two options.

- Distribute only your script. Your friends would have to separately download and install Python. Assuming this is a `tkinter` script, it should have the extension `.pyw`, otherwise `.py`. Sometimes the OS doesn't know what to do with `.pyw` files, and you have to tell it to always open them with `pythonw.exe`.
- Make a self-contained executable package with e.g. [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/) and distribute that.

POSIX platforms like Linux, *BSD and OS X generally either come with Python or have it easily available in their standard packaging system. So distributing the script is sufficient in that case.